# How to filter array value in object javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have object which contains array, I want to filter the object based on array value.

**For example:**

```
    {
       "sun":["sleep","walk"],
       "mon":["read","dance","ride"],
       "tue":["work","dance","sleep"],
    }
```

if I enter keyword "sleep" then result should be as follows

```
    {
      "sun":["sleep"],
      "tue":["sleep"],
    }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Did you try the obvious: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) -> [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) -> [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)?

Comment: @Wyck I don't have much idea about that can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the object and do the manipulations, please find working code below:

```js
const obj = {
  "sun": ["sleep", 'walk'],
  "mon": ["read", "dance", "ride"],
  "tue": ["work", "dance", "sleep"],
}

function filterIt(filterString) {
  const result = {};
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop].includes(filterString)) {
      result[prop] = [filterString];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const finalResult = filterIt('sleep');
console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Useful tools for solving this problem:

- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let obj =
{
  "sun": ["sleep", "walk"],
  "mon": ["read", "dance", "ride"],
  "tue": ["work", "dance", "sleep"],
};

let result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(kvp => kvp[1].includes('sleep'))
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v.filter(o => o === 'sleep')])
  )

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.keys`, `map`, `includes`.

```
let obj ={
       "sun":["sleep","walk"],
       "mon":["read","dance","ride"],
       "tue":["work","dance","sleep"],
    }

let new_obj = {}
let search = 'sleep'

Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
     obj[key].includes(search) ? new_obj[key]=[search] : ''
})

console.log(new_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.transform()` to create a new object. Check if the value array (`v`) includes the `str`, and if it does assign the key with a new array that includes the str:

```js
const fn = (obj, str) => _.transform(obj, (o, v, k) => {
  if(v.includes(str)) o[k] = [str]
})

const obj = {
  "sun":["sleep","walk"],
  "mon":["read","dance","ride"],
  "tue":["work","dance","sleep"],
}

const result = fn(obj, 'sleep')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```